# Gitlab prompts for git password when cloning a git repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have installed GitLab 7.9.1 using Omnibus.

Everything works. When I do a gitlab-rake gitlab:check, I get no errors.

However, when I want to clone a repository in /var/www, the console prompts me for a git password.

I have added the SSH key in the Gitlab interface. However, it still asks me for a git password when I try to clone a repository.

What do you think?

p.s I will like to point out that I have used the Omnibus installation and not installation from source.

Comment: This suggests that the necessary private key is not available to your ssh client.  If your private key is (a) not `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and (b) is not loaded into an ssh-agent, you would need to point git at the key explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely forgot to provide the solution. I actually had fixed the problem. It was a problem with the SSH keys.

I followed the guide on gitlabs on how to generate SSH keys. I didn't follow it properly. I missed the email address in 'ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "****@***.com"'

It works now.

Answer (score 6):

I hit the same issue. For me the problem was that /etc/ssh/sshd_config had an AllowGroups directive that did not include the git group created by gitlab (viewing /var/log/secure spelled it out).

I appended git to the set of groups listed after AllowGroups, ran `sudo /sbin/service sshd restart`, and then `git clone git@...` worked as expected. Similarly, after the fix I can run `ssh git@gitlab.hostname` and it responds with "Welcome to GitLab..." which is an easy way to confirm the ssh keys setup is fine w/o accessing a specific repo.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to clone with a HTTP URL? If so, git will ask for username and password. Try cloning with SSH URL; this will make git use the SSH keys that have been set up.

Answer (score 0):

I have met with the same error when trying to clone using SSH on Windows:

> Cloning into 'some_project'... 
>   git@git.company.com's password: 
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

The key was accessible, but the mistake was **using command prompt (cmd.exe) instead of Git Cmd (git-cmd.exe).**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it turned out to be SELinux blocking sshd from reading and opening the file authorized_keys.

```
Aug  9 04:10:36 gitlab01 setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing sshd from read access on the file authorized_keys. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l bdda8979-07aa-47bd-baac-e818c54abb49
```

I implemented a new selinux policy and was all good.

```
~$ cat local-gitlab.te
module local-gitlab 1.0;

require {
    type var_t;
    type sshd_t;
    class file getattr;
    class file read;
    class file open;
}

#============= sshd_t ==============

#!!!! WARNING: 'var_t' is a base type.
allow sshd_t var_t:file getattr;
allow sshd_t var_t:file read;
allow sshd_t var_t:file open;
```